# Does Protandim "reduce age-related symptoms"?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine

I have a friend who sells some sort of supplement called "[Protandim](http://www.protandim.com/)", and I'm wondering if it actually works or is any good. I'm skeptical of it, but I'm not aware of any evidence either way.

> The unique blend of phytonutrients in Protandim signal your body’s genes to
>   produce special antioxidant enzymes, SOD (superoxide dismutase) CAT (catalase)
>   that work together as the body’s first line of defense against free radicals.*
>   These enzymes are “catalytic,” which means that SOD and CAT are not used up
>   when they neutralize free radicals. A single daily caplet of Protandim creates
>   a cascade of your body’s natural catalytic antioxidants that are able to
>   destroy millions of free radicals per second, on a continuous basis–24/7.*

Comment: Sigh. Why is Elsivier publishing "[clinical proof](http://www.protandim.com/pdf/ProtandimFRBMpaperJan152006.pdf)" without a real control?

Comment: Ah... catalytic enzymes... as opposed to the non catalytic ones I would think?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on two questions:

1) Does Protandim activate *NRF2* in normal persons to increase the level of SOD and CAT in many cell types?

**Answer**: one in-vitro study has shown this for curcumin, a part of Protandim, and kidney cells[1]; there are no clinical studies.

2) Do higher levels of SOD and CAT, probably leading to lower "radicals" (to be exact, SOD neutralizes O2-, and KAT H2O2 which are not radicals but can lead to such), reduce age-related symptoms?

**Answer**: there is growing evidence that oxidative stress is actually needed by the body[2], one example being macrophages producing O2-, H2O2, and NO- to kill bacteria).

[1] Balogun E, Hoque M, Gong P, Killeen E, Green CJ, Foresti R, Alam J, Motterlini R (2003). "[Curcumin activates the haem oxygenase-1 gene via regulation of Nrf2 and the antioxidant-responsive element](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12570874)". Biochem J 371 (10): 887–95. DOI:10.1042/BJ20021619. PMC 1223348. PMID 12570874.

[2] [Wikipedia page on antioxidant supplements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antioxidant#Potential_of_antioxidant_supplements_to_damage_health)
and the refs therein